# Check if two strings are anagram

Tags: algorithm, stack, anagram, array-algorithms

I want to return true if string t is an anagram of s. I have pushed all characters of s in the stack and comparing each character of t with the top element in the stack, if the character matches, i perform the pop operation. If at the end, stack is empty, this means the string t is an anagram of string s. Here is my code -

```
public boolean isAnagram(String s, String t) {
    char[] charArray1 = s.toCharArray();
    char[] charArray2 = t.toCharArray();
    if (s.length() != t.length())
    {
        return false;
    }
    Stack<Character> newStack = new Stack<Character>();
    for (int i=0; i<charArray1.length;i++)
    {
        newStack.push(charArray1[i]);
    }
    for (int j=0;j<charArray2.length;j++)
    {
        if(charArray2[j] == newStack.peek())
        {
            newStack.pop();
        }
    }
    if (newStack.isEmpty())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    return false;
}



error: s= "abc", t= "bac", Doesn't seem to declare these two strings as anagram
```

Comment: Sort the characters in the string into alphabetical order then compare

Comment: @samgak The above logic should work even when the strings are not sorted,

Comment: Why do you want to use a stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stack is the wrong data structure for this problem, because `peek()` only looks at the top element of the stack, but you want to check if each character in `charArray2` can be found *anywhere* in `charArray1`. A simpler approach is to sort the arrays and then compare them as `Strings`:

```
public boolean isAnagram(String s, String t) {
    char[] charArray1 = s.toCharArray();
    char[] charArray2 = t.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(charArray1);
    Arrays.sort(charArray2);
    String string1 = new String(charArray1);
    String string2 = new String(charArray2);
    return string1.contentEquals(string2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use stack explicitly.  Use any of the below methods.

### Use Sorting:

1) Sort both strings
2) Compare the sorted strings

"Or"

### Count characters and store it in array:

This method assumes that the set of possible characters in both strings is small. In the following implementation, it is assumed that the characters are stored using 8 bit and there can be 256 possible characters.
1) Create count arrays of size 256 for both strings. Initialize all values in count arrays as 0.
2) Iterate through every character of both strings and increment the count of character in the corresponding count arrays.
3) Compare count arrays. If both count arrays are same, then return true.